# Find the 2nd highest element

Tags: python

1. In a given array how to find the 2nd,  3rd, 4th,  or 5th values?
2. Also  if we use the`max()` function in python what is the order of complexity i.e, associated with this function `max()`?

.

```
def nth_largest(li,n):   
    li.remove(max(li))
    print max(ele)  //will give me the second largest
    #how to make a general algorithm to find the 2nd,3rd,4th highest value
    #n is the element to be found  below the highest value
```

Comment: If you have the list `[1,2,2]`, what do you want as the second largest element?  `1` or `2`?

Comment: i want it to be 1 in your case

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd go for:

```
import heapq
res = heapq.nlargest(2, some_sequence)
print res[1] # to get 2nd largest
```

This is more efficient than sorting the entire list, then taking the first `n` many elements. See the [heapq documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) for further info.

Comment: what is the order of complexity of max()

Comment: @Hulk you'd have to scan the list twice for `max`... This scans it once, and retains the two largest using a heap queue

Comment: Since he specified that he only wants to count unique elements (i.e. [1,2,2] should return 1 not 2, you first have to make the list a set for this to give the expected result.

Comment: But import is also a costly operation then why not use inbuilt sorting method

Comment: @Hulk because `sorting` is potentially a far more expensive operation both cpu time and memory wise... using this approach doesn't require having the entire list sorted in memory as the size can be capped to two while building the result...

Comment: @JonClements why you said you have to scan the list twice for max? To obtain the maximum number in a list of numbers you only have to scan the list once, hence it takes O(n) time. as Jo Are By said.

Comment: @JuanCatalan Jon meant that you have to scan the list twice to get the *second* greatest element with `max()`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `sorted(set(element))`:

```
>>> a = (0, 11, 100, 11, 33, 33, 55)
>>>
>>> sorted(set(a))[-1] # highest
100
>>> sorted(set(a))[-2] # second highest
55
>>>
```

as a function:

```
def nth_largest(li, n):
    return sorted(set(li))[-n]
```

test:

```
>>> a = (0, 11, 100, 11, 33, 33, 55)
>>> def nth_largest(li, n):
...     return sorted(set(li))[-n]
...
>>>
>>> nth_largest(a, 1)
100
>>> nth_largest(a, 2)
55
>>>
```

Note, here you only need to sort and remove the duplications once, if you worry about the performance you could cache the result of `sorted(set(li))`.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is a concern (e.g.: you intend to call this a lot), then you should absolutely keep the list sorted and de-duplicated at all times, and simply the first, second, or nth element (which is `o(1)`).

Use the [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module for this - it's faster than a "standard" `sort`.

`insort` lets you insert an element, and `bisect` will let you find whether you should be inserting at all (to avoid duplicates).

---

If it's not, I'd suggest the simpler:

```
def nth_largest(li, n):.
    return sorted(set(li))[-(n+1)]
```

If the reverse indexing looks ugly to you, you can do:

```
def nth_largest(li, n):
    return sorted(set(li), reverse=True)[n]
```

Answer (score 2):

As for which method would have the lowest time complexity, this depends a lot on which types of queries you plan on making.

If you're planning on making queries into high indexes (e.g. 36th largest element in a list with 38 elements), your function `nth_largest(li,n)` will  have close to O(n^2) time complexity since it will have to do max, which is O(n), several times. It will be similar to the Selection Sort algorithm except using `max()` instead of `min()`.

On the other hand, if you are only making low index queries, then your function can be efficient as it will only apply the O(n) `max` function a few times and the time complexity will be close to O(n). However, building a max heap is possible in linear time O(n) and you would be better off just using that. After you go through the trouble of constructing a heap, all of your `max()` operations on the heap will be O(1) which could be a better long-term solution for you.

I believe the most scalable way (in terms of being able to query nth largest element for *any* n) is to sort the list with time complexity O(n log n) using the built-in `sort` function and then make O(1) queries from the sorted list. Of course, that's not the most memory-efficient method but in terms of time complexity it is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using numpy (`import numpy as np`):

```
np.partition(numbers, -i)[-i]
```

gives you [the *i*th largest element of the list with a guaranteed worst-case **O(n)** running time](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html).

The `partition(a, kth)` methods returns an array where the `k`th element is the same it would be in a sorted array, all elements before are smaller, and all behind are larger.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
sorted(li)[::-1][n]
```

Comment: `.reverse` acts in-place and returns None.

Comment: Let me try again: your code right now won't work, because `li_s.reverse()` gives `None`, and `None[n]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just do `sorted(li, reverse=True)[n]` save mucking about reversing the list after the sort...

Comment: Seriously, "don't be so picky"? (a) your solution didn't work AT ALL until Jon rewrote it for you; and (b) being a good developer is all about being picky. Tell us where you work so we can avoid e.g. riding in any elevators you wrote the control system for.

Comment: I rewrote it myself. "Don't be picky" is a joke. Don't be so serious.