# How to make second maximum values as new column in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {

    'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'Price1':[5,9,4,3,9],
    'Price2':[9,10,13,14,18],
    'Price3':[5,9,4,3,9],
    'Price4':[9,10,13,14,18],
    'Price5':[5,9,4,3,9],
    'Price6':[np.nan,10,13,14,18],
    'Price7':[np.nan,9,4,3,9],
    'Price8':[np.nan,10,13,14,18],
    'Price9':[5,9,4,3,9],
    'Price10':[9,10,13,14,18],
     'Type':['A','A','B','C','D'],


}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

How to compare Price 1 to Price 10 columns and add second max value as new column?

Expected Output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {

    'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'Price1':[5,9,4,3,9],
    'Price2':[9,10,13,14,18],
    'Price3':[5,9,4,3,9],
    'Price4':[9,10,13,14,18],
    'Price5':[5,9,4,3,9],
    'Price6':[np.nan,10,13,14,18],
    'Price7':[np.nan,9,4,3,9],
    'Price8':[np.nan,10,13,14,18],
    'Price9':[5,9,4,3,9],
    'Price10':[9,10,13,14,18],
     'Type':['A','A','B','C','D'],
    'Second_Max':[5,9,4,3,18]


}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

How to compare Price 1 to Price 10 columns and add second max value as new column?

Comment: by second max do you mean the second highest number in in the row?

Comment: @JDD yes I mean that

Answer (score 3):

one way to do this

```
df['Second_Max'] = df.drop(['ID','Type'], axis=1).fillna(0).apply(lambda x: (sorted(list(set(x)), reverse=True))[1], axis=1)
```

or

```
df['Second_Max'] =  df.filter(like='Price').fillna(0).apply(lambda x: (sorted(list(set(x)), reverse=True))[1], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   ID  Price1  Price2  Price3  Price4  Price5  Price6  Price7  Price8  Price9  \
0   1       5       9       5       9       5     NaN     NaN     NaN       5   
1   2       9      10       9      10       9    10.0     9.0    10.0       9   
2   3       4      13       4      13       4    13.0     4.0    13.0       4   
3   4       3      14       3      14       3    14.0     3.0    14.0       3   
4   5       9      18       9      18       9    18.0     9.0    18.0       9   

   Price10 Type  Second_Max  
0        9    A         5.0  
1       10    A         9.0  
2       13    B         4.0  
3       14    C         3.0  
4       18    D         9.0
```

or more efficient way would be to use [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html)

[Find the 2nd highest element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549730/find-the-2nd-highest-element)

Comment: `df.filter(like='Price').apply(...)` will also be a good option here. (IMO):) +1

Comment: Also, it should be `-1` on the list i think no?

Answer (score 2):

Use `lambda` function along axis=1, then use [nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) to get top 2 elements..

```
df['Second_Max'] = df.iloc[:,:-1].apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().nlargest(2)[1], 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding another way using [`np.sort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
m=df.filter(like='Price')
df['second_highest']=abs(np.sort(-m.apply(lambda x:
                    x.drop_duplicates(),axis=1),axis=1))[:,1]
print(df)
```

May be another way without `apply()` would be:

```
m=df.filter(like='Price')
df['second_highest']=(m.T.sort_values(m.index.tolist(),ascending=False).
                          drop_duplicates().iloc[1])
```

Comment: it works how to find three, four, five max values as new column? Can you help?

Comment: @panda if you do `m.rank(axis=1,method='dense',ascending=False)` you will see there is no 3, means there is no 3rd greater value per row. Would be good if you post a fresh question and share the link with us. :)

Comment: sure will do it and post

Comment: please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55936667/how-to-find-max-values-of-columns-and-arrange-them-in-order-using-pandas

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `np.unique` after `np.sort`:

```
df['Second_Max'] = df.filter(like='Price').apply(lambda x: np.unique(np.sort(x.dropna()))[-2], axis=1)

   ID  Price1  Price2  Price3  Price4  Price5  Price6  Price7  Price8  Price9  Price10 Type  Second_Max
0   1       5       9       5       9       5     NaN     NaN     NaN       5        9    A         5.0
1   2       9      10       9      10       9    10.0     9.0    10.0       9       10    A         9.0
2   3       4      13       4      13       4    13.0     4.0    13.0       4       13    B         4.0
3   4       3      14       3      14       3    14.0     3.0    14.0       3       14    C         3.0
4   5       9      18       9      18       9    18.0     9.0    18.0       9       18    D         9.0
```