# How to find max values of columns and arrange them in order based on condition using pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {

    'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'Price1':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price2':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price5':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price6':[np.nan,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price10':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price3':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price4':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price7':[np.nan,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price8':[np.nan,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price9':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Type':['A','A','B','C','D','D'],


}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

How to find max values of columns and arrange them in order  based on condition using pandas?

Find maximum of Price 1, Price 2, Price 5, Price6, Price10 and add as new column as maxA

Find maximum of Price 3, Price 4, Price 7, Price8, Price9 and add as new column as maxB

Expected Output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {

    'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'Price1':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price2':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price3':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price4':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price5':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price6':[np.nan,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price7':[np.nan,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price8':[np.nan,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'Price9':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'Price10':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
     'Type':['A','A','B','C','D','D'],
    'maxA1':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'maxA2':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'maxA3':[5,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'maxA4':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'maxA5':[np.nan,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'maxB1':[9,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'maxB2':[5,10,13,14,18,np.nan],
    'maxB3':[5,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'maxB4':[np.nan,9,4,3,9,np.nan],
    'maxB5':[np.nan,9,4,3,9,np.nan],


}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
pd.set_option('max_columns',25)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
c1 = ['Price1', 'Price2', 'Price5','Price6','Price10']
col1=[f"maxA{i+1}" for i in range(len(c1))]
#['maxA1', 'maxA2', 'maxA3', 'maxA4', 'maxA5']
c2 = ['Price3', 'Price4', 'Price7', 'Price8', 'Price9']
col2=[f"maxB{i+1}" for i in range(len(c2))]
#['maxB1', 'maxB2', 'maxB3', 'maxB4', 'maxB5']
```

---

```
a = pd.DataFrame(abs(np.sort(-df[c1],axis=1)),columns=col1)
b=pd.DataFrame(abs(np.sort(-df[c2],axis=1)),columns=col2)
```

---

```
df_new=pd.concat([df,a,b],axis=1)
print(df_new)
```

---

```
   ID  Price1  Price2  Price5  Price6  Price10  Price3  Price4  Price7  \
0   1     5.0     9.0     5.0     NaN      9.0     5.0     9.0     NaN   
1   2     9.0    10.0     9.0    10.0     10.0     9.0    10.0     9.0   
2   3     4.0    13.0     4.0    13.0     13.0     4.0    13.0     4.0   
3   4     3.0    14.0     3.0    14.0     14.0     3.0    14.0     3.0   
4   5     9.0    18.0     9.0    18.0     18.0     9.0    18.0     9.0   
5   6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   

   Price8  Price9 Type  maxA1  maxA2  maxA3  maxA4  maxA5  maxB1  maxB2  \
0     NaN     5.0    A    9.0    9.0    5.0    5.0    NaN    9.0    5.0   
1    10.0     9.0    A   10.0   10.0   10.0    9.0    9.0   10.0   10.0   
2    13.0     4.0    B   13.0   13.0   13.0    4.0    4.0   13.0   13.0   
3    14.0     3.0    C   14.0   14.0   14.0    3.0    3.0   14.0   14.0   
4    18.0     9.0    D   18.0   18.0   18.0    9.0    9.0   18.0   18.0   
5     NaN     NaN    D    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   

   maxB3  maxB4  maxB5  
0    5.0    NaN    NaN  
1    9.0    9.0    9.0  
2    4.0    4.0    4.0  
3    3.0    3.0    3.0  
4    9.0    9.0    9.0  
5    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: df is fully np.nan for my original dataset

Comment: I mean after pd.concat my df part data frame becomes null

Comment: I am not doing reassigning even I tried df_new = df.join(a, how='outer')
df_new = df_new.join(b, how='outer')
print (df_new) it also gives nan for df could you please help

Comment: @panda just print df now? what do you see? also are index of df, a and b same?

Comment: I got the issue index of df is different and index of a, b starts with o. How can I restart index of df from 0?

Comment: @panda `df=df.reset_index(drop=True)`